# Exception: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessage

Tags: magento2, email-templates

Getting error when trying to send email via controller

```
 $email_Template = 'hello_template';  
    $email_Subject = 'Customer Registration Success';

    $transport = $this->transportBuilder
        ->setTemplateIdentifier($email_Template)
        ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()])
        ->setTemplateVars([
            'name'  => 'aaaa',
            'email'  => $data['email'],
            'subject'  => $email_Subject
        ])
        ->setFrom(['name' => 'test','email' => 'test@gmail.com'])
        ->addTo([$data['email']])
        ->getTransport();
    $transport->sendMessage();
```

How to debug the error.

I have already tried by removing generated folder & re run all magento2 compilation commands

I am using Magento2.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following code:

```
->addTo([$data['email']])
```

To

```
->addTo($data['email'], 'Name')
```

Comment: I did this above change in my code, but still getting the same error. Can you please help here?